# Symbol not found: _LAErrorDomain

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, touch-id

App crashes with `Symbol not found: _LAErrorDomain`, when using `LAErrorDomain` (from the Local Authentication framework for Touch ID) on iOS below version 8.3. Works fine on iOS 8.3 though.

Compiled with Xcode 6.3.2 and iOS SDK 8.3. Update: Still the same with Xcode 6.4 and iOS SDK 8.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really weird one. I don't really understand what causes this, because `LAErrorDomain` should be available as a constant since iOS 8.0. Maybe someone knows the true issue here, but here's my workaround:

Luckily the error domain of Local Authentication is also defined as a macro in `<LocalAuthentication/LAPublicDefines.h>`, which is already imported, if you are using Local Authentication.

You can either use `kLAErrorDomain` directly (more precisely `@kLAErrorDomain`, because the macro is defined as a string literal) or define your own constant:

```
// Workaround for iOS below 8.3: LAErrorDomain constant can't be found and leads to a crash
NSString *const MyLAErrorDomain = @kLAErrorDomain;
```

Comment: Apple corrected later versions of the header to note that the LAErrorDomain symbol is only available on iOS 8.3 and later.  So you need the workaround if you are supporting any iOS 8.x system.